# Obtain the number of the item in an options menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm using `.val()` in jQuery to retain the value of an options menu `onChange`.

How would I retain the number (as in as it is ordered) of the item in the drop down using jQuery?

```
<select>
     <option>  //option 1
     <option>  //option 2
</select>
```

Here is what I have set up now:

```
<select id="start_month" onChange="getMonthDay()">
         <option>Jan</option>
         <option>Feb</option>
         <option>March</option>
         <option>April</option>
<select>
```

Using,

```
function getMonthDay()
{

$('#start_month').val()
}
```

I can get whatever value is selected, but my question is how do I get the Number down of this value in the markup?  For March, I would want 3.. and so on

Comment: could you clarify a bit please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you reformulate your question better? I'm still lost in what do you want.

But, nevertheless here is how `<select>` works in jQuery

```
<select id="selection">
  <option value="val_1">value 1</option>
  <option value="val_2">value 2</option>
</select>
```

`$("#selection").val()` will give you `val_1` or `val_2` depending on witch item is currently selected.

If you want to go through all options and check the selected on, you can use

```
$("#selection option:selected").val();
```

or itenerate through all `<option>`'s

```
$("#selection option").each(function() {

    if( $(this).is(":selected") ) {

        var v = $(this).val();

    }

});
```

If you want to retain all options you can easily [clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) them or assign them as [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/), if you want to keep those values throughout the pages, use Local Database or Cookies to persist the data.

---

To answer your question after your update:

**First:** Why don't you have:

```
<select id="start_month" onChange="getMonthDay()">
    <option value="1">Jan</option>
    <option value="2">Feb</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
<select>
```

And use the value of the selected item?

**Second:** Just use what I wrote above and itenerate through the options

```
$("#start_month option").each(function(index, element) {

    if( $(this).is(":selected") ) {

        // get index position, remember to add 1 as arrays start at 0
        var n = index;

        // break each
        return false;

    }

});
```

Comment: Look at what I have added above, thank you for an answer though

Answer (score 0):

You'd get a list of the `<option>` elements, find the selected one, and use [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
var $opts = $('#start_month option');
var zero_based_index = $opts.index($opts.filter(':selected'));
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/HyukW/

Just add 1 if you want a one-based index.

Comment: the faster way :) though I still dont get why he does not use the `value` as `<option value="1">Jan</option>` ... :-/

Comment: @balexandre: Could be useful for synchronizing two lists. Or there could be a gigantic corporate bureaucratic mess behind that I don't want to know about :)

Answer (score 0):

I made something like this,with zero based key ;

```
<select id='deneme'>
    <option>Val1</option>
    <option>Val2</option>
    <option>Val3</option>
    <option>Val4</option>
</select>

$('#deneme').change(function(){
        $.each( $('#deneme').children('option'),function(key,value){
            if($(this).is(':selected'))
                alert(key)
        })
})
```

u can check from here http://jsfiddle.net/8JZCw/

Answer (score 0):

No need for any iteration here, let jQuery do that for you, just get the selected index and increment...

```
$('#start_month option:selected').index() + 1
```